# Would anyone else enjoy a way to see reputation earned by activity?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, reputation-history

I was looking at the reputation tag, and I liked the way it shows each of the activities that caused reputation changes:
[image]

I think it would be interesting to see a breakdown of all rep ever gained, like:

- +150 by Upvoted Answers
- +150 by Accepted Answers
- +150 by Accepted Edits
- +150 by Upvoted Questions
- -150 by Downvoted Questions
- -50 by Downvoting Answers

And so on, and not necessarily in that order. This was just a thought, wanted to see what everyone else's take on it was.

Comment: This feature makes a lot less sense once you hit the repcap. You get 20 answer upvotes and 40 question upvotes for a total of 200 rep. Did you get 200 from questions and 0 from answers? 0 from questions and 200 from answers? Half and half? Count only votes before the cap?

Comment: @Mysticial I didn't think about it that way, that's a good point. However, that would make another interesting option, maybe to see a total breakdown of upvotes earned on questions, answers, total accepted edits, total downvotes on questions,  and so on.

Comment: @Mysticial:  If it were broken down by day, I could see functionality which denoted the event of an upvote, but not actually recording its reputation points (which makes sense).

Comment: Don't forget bounties awarded by you, and bounties awarded to you.  There are losses from users being removed, or questions being migrated.  It might be useful to have counts of the number of up-votes you've received separately from the number of points you've received from up-votes (because of rate-capping).

Comment: @Mysticial 100 question rep, 400 answer rep, -300 cap rep?

Comment: @Mysticial - pretty simple, actually.  That would show you .... how you earned the rep.  So if you get 20 answer upvotes, followed by a million question upvotes, then it would show you 200 rep from the former, and nothing from the latter.  Or 40 question upvotes followed by a hundred answer upvotes would show you 200 rep from question upvotes.  And so on.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152413/chart-to-show-reputation-points-grouped-by-event-type

Comment: @bjb568 I like that a lot. It would add a whole new category: reputation lost due to rep limit'. This way, the entire chart would even out to your actual reputation, but you can still see the *possible* rep earned.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I found a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/220825/my-reputation-graph#graph) which is wonderful for this purpose. But personally I am not really concerned about knowing my rep for one type of activity :)

And, by the way, you can check stats for your virtual rep on MSO. Just switch the site.

Comment: Wow, that's really cool! On a side question, this says I've gained 795 from accepted answers (which comes out to 53) but I really have 54 as of today. Is this accessing a read-only database that is updated during a certain period?

Comment: @McAdam331 data explorer isn't querying the live database, it's a copy that is periodically updated, which would explain the discrepancy.

Comment: @McAdam yeah, its not realtime.

Comment: @Tanner and nicael, this is new to me. Is it open to everyone? I would assume that it is still read-only so that data is not manipulated.

Comment: @McA It is read-only, updated by SE and updated... every week if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I'm not getting any results with this query.  I've added my SO user id and its empty.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What a bear of a query. But indeed cool that you can do this.

Comment: @paq [Seems to work for me...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4yyBJ.png)

Comment: So what are the chances something like this actually gets implemented into Stack somewhere, rather than having to come to this question or bookmark the query.

Comment: Now that I've looked at the MSO one, I see it doesn't include activities past cap rep, either. I have [320 question upvotes](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/220825/my-reputation-graph?uid=3131147#graph) which divided by 5 points per upvote is 64. I have 84 upvotes on this question alone.

Comment: @McA 1. I don't know anything official about it, maybe or maybe not... 2. But it gives you the desired result - rep for this activity? :) your question was about rep.

Comment: It was, but I do think mysticial pointed out a big loophole to that idea. However, this is still really cool, and exactly what I was looking for initially.